# How do I the site logo depending on the URL the request was made from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I created a product registration page using ASP.Net MVC. I need to implement the same product registration page for subsidiaries (maybe 3 or 4) with a few minor changes to the way the site looks. For example, the logo will be different and some text at the top of the page. What is the best way to use the same codebase?

The best option I could come up with is passing HttpContext.Current.Request.URL to the view and using java script to update it.

However, I know routing can be an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be keeping the same .cshtml view for all registration pages then i think creating a partial view for logo generation would probably help you out.

Add another variable to your view model.. maybe call it subsidiary?

```
public int Subsidiary { get; set; }
```

then create a partial view called something like _LogoPartial.cshtml and in there do a if statement on the Subsidiary variable and return a different logo based on it

```
@model int

@if (Model == 1)
{
   <img src="something" />
}
else if ...
```

then in your main view call it with

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_LogoPartial", Model.Subsidiary);
```